# nodejs backbone and passportjs

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, passport.js

i am using nodejs (with express) and backbone. I would like to integrate passport.js for facebook authentication.
I have the following route:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: [ 'email', 'user_about_me'], failureRedirect: '/login' }), users.signin);
```

What should I do in case the user logged in successfully? How can I access to the user data?
What should I do in case the user DID NOT log in successfully? How can I open the facebook dialog?

Are there any good examples of using passport.js with single page applications?

Answer (score 0):

I know I am answering late but in case you haven't been able to figure out how to use facebook  strategy of passport yet, you can go through example provided [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/tree/master/examples/login).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful for you :)

Here is the solution recently I have done the facebook connect with passport

I assume you install the passport modules

**app.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');
require('./lib/connect')(passport); // pass passport for configuration
```

**routes.js**

```
// send to facebook to do the authentication
app.get('/auth/facebook', 
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' })
);
```

I have created a lib file

**connect.js**

```
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
module.exports = function(passport) {
 passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID        : facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret    : facebookAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL     : facebookAuth.callbackURL,
    passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass in the req from our route
    },
    function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
        // here you can get the user profile info
        console.log("profile : "+JSON.stringify(profile));
        // asynchronous
        process.nextTick(function() {
            //your logic
        });
    });
};
```